# Google OAuth2 Java code asking permissions every time

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am using the following with a google-client-secret.json file and trying to run this as just a java application in eclipse. I want to store the permissions so once I accept the permissions it doesn't ask again. Right now it is prompting everytime. After that everything works as expected and writes to my google sheets.

```
    public static Credential authorizeSHEETS() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        File fileIn = new File("src/jg/sos/orders/google-sheets-client-secret.json");
//        InputStream in = GoogleAuthorizeUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("src/jg/sos/orders/google-sheets-client-secret.json");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileIn);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new InputStreamReader(in));

        List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);

        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), clientSecrets, scopes).setDataStoreFactory(new MemoryDataStoreFactory())
                .setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

        return credential;
    }
```

Any ideas on how to only have this prompt me the first time for permissions, then the next time I run this it will not?

Thanks for the help!
JJ

Answer (score 1):

So found an answer to this in case anyone comes across. I used a service account instead, and downloaded the json file for it and placed in my project.

Then I just referenced it instead, and saved the token using DataStoreFactory as below:

```
public static Credential authorizeSHEETS() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
            File fileIn = new File("src/jg/sos/orders/google-sheets-client-secret.json");
    //        InputStream in = GoogleAuthorizeUtil.class.getResourceAsStream("src/jg/sos/orders/google-sheets-client-secret.json");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileIn);
            GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), new InputStreamReader(in));
    
            List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS);
            
            FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File("src/jg/sos/orders"));
    
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(), JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), clientSecrets, scopes)
                    .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                    .setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();
            
            Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
            
            System.out.println("token" + credential.getAccessToken());
    
            return credential;
        }
```

Comment: I tried your solution and it is working. Thanks for this snippet.